# Read/Writing files in node with fs via UNC path

Tags: node.js, unc, fs

Having issues of `reading/writing` to a UNC path with `nodeJs` on my local machine. At one point `fs` was read/writing from my machine to the UNC path just fine, but now it appears that it cannot read/write to it.

UNC Path : 
 `\\[machine name]\folder1\folder2\file.csv`

I upgraded to node version 12 awhile back and thought perhaps there is a network path bug, but not seeing anyone online affected. I then used `nvmw` to load an older version of node and still nothing.

I wondered if it was because I was not joined to the same domain, however, that was not an issue before. I can ping the box, access in windows explorer, remote in.

I have tried running my app as my user, as admin, added a windows credential for network admin in credential manager.

Tried changing the flags used for permissions `r`, `r+`, `a`, `a+` 0666...

Paths Tried

- `\\[machine name]\`
- `\\?\[machine name]\`
- `\\?\UNC\[machine name]\`

**Write Error**

```
{ 
  [Error: UNKNOWN, mkdir '\\[machine name]\Storage\CSV\Example.csv']
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  path: '\\[machine name]\Storage\CSV\Example.csv' 
}
```

**Read Error**

```
{ 
  [Error: UNKNOWN, open '\\[machine name]\Storage\CSV\Example.csv']
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  path: '\\[machine name]\Storage\CSV\Example.csv' 
}
```

I have walked through a lot of the actual fs code and it seems to ultimately generate the appropriate path but doesnt seem to vibe well with the windows for accessing the UNC path.

I am hoping someone can give me a few pointers of things to check or possible reasons for this.

Comment: Maybe related: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8821#issuecomment-77834980

Comment: Not sure.  I ended up deleting virtual network connections...and entirely resetting my network adapter and all of a sudden it was back up and writing files.  I dont know if those are what fixed it or not.  It has been a crummy thing to try and figure out though

Comment: I ran into this too, but I was able to use a drive it was already mapped to instead (although it's not hard to add one)

Comment: You mean you're on node `0.12`? Try 7... Might be fixed there now?

Answer (score 4):

As you know in node, the backslash is the escape character, so you will need to double the number of backslashes you use.  For:

```
\\machine name\folder1\folder2\filename.ext
```

try:

```
\\\\machine name\\folder1\\folder2\\filename.ext
```

Comment: What is the answer? in the question, he is already using double backslash!

Comment: Sorry, did not see that answer in edit mode was different that display mode.  I modified the answer in edit mode to display correctly